# Installing Windows after Ubuntu (Grub lost)

Tags: grub2, windows

I have an Ubuntu system on which I installed Windows knowing that I would lose GRUB. Now Windows is installed properly, but while booting I am not able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows. It directly boots to Windows but I can see the Ubuntu partition. How do I restore GRUB?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader and: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System  If newer UEFI, you should just be able to use one time boot key like f10 or f12 check manual and boot ubuntu. IF not what brand/model system as some need work arounds.

Comment: only command line is appearing

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu using a live-usb (Select try Ubuntu when asked).

Open terminal and install 'boot-repair':

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and choose the [Recommended Repair](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1335260967.png).

Comment: More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair